# Get an error 'unknown field "data"' when try to deploy an Ingress object to a kube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Here is the config of the Ingress object:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  labels:
    app: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 1024m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 5000
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-conditional-samesite-none: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
data:
  proxy-hide-headers: "Server"
  server-tokens: "False"
spec:
  rules:
      ...
```

When I do `kubectl apply` to create this Ingress I got the next error:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress): unknown field "data" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1beta1.Ingress
```

The cluster version is 1.21.0.

After a long search in google didn't find any clue why this error can happen, didn't find any deprecation of this field. Please help.

Comment: Did solution of @vijay help you?

Answer (score 0):

So looking by error it says that apiversion (networking.k8s.io/v1beta1) you mentioned in yaml file is unable to identify the object data.

It looks like policies version has been changed from **v1beta1** to **v1**. could you verify the version you have or change it to v1 and try.
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an invalid object for the api-resource ingress.

```yaml
data:
  proxy-hide-headers: "Server"
  server-tokens: "False"
```

remove the above fields and try to add them via a `configmap` for the ingress.
configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-hide-headers: "Server"
  server-tokens: "False"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-cm
```

And configure your pod to mount the nginx configmap. To know the allowed objects always run `kubectl explain api-resource` eg: `kubectl explain ingress`.

More details on custom configuration can be found in [kubernetes.github.io](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/) site.